# How to translate this command into a makefile file?

Tags: gcc, makefile

```
gcc testr.c -L/usr/local/hdf/hdf5/lib /usr/local/hdf/hdf5/lib/libhdf5_hl.a /usr/local/hdf/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.a -ldl -lstdc++ -lm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/hdf/hdf5/lib -I /usr/local/hdf/hdf5/include
```

there is a source file named testr.c, above is the command, and the below is my unfinished example.

```
LIB=-L/usr/local/hdf/hdf5/lib
INC=-I/usr/local/hdf/hdf5/include

testr: testr.c
     gcc -o testr testr.c -I.
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the simplest conversion possible:

```
something:
    gcc testr.c -L/usr/local/hdf/hdf5/lib /usr/local/hdf/hdf5/lib/libhdf5_hl.a /usr/local/hdf/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.a -ldl -lstdc++ -lm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/hdf/hdf5/lib -I /usr/local/hdf/hdf5/include
```

We notice that `usr/local/hdf/hdf5` comes up a lot, so we put that in a variable:

```
HDF5 := /usr/local/hdf/hdf5

something:
    gcc testr.c -L$(HDF5)/lib $(HDF5)/lib/libhdf5_hl.a $(HDF5)/lib/libhdf5.a -ldl -lstdc++ -lm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,$(HDF5)/lib -I $(HDF5)/include
```

Now it's clear that you can invoke the static libraries in a more concise way:

```
something:
    gcc testr.c -L$(HDF5)/lib -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -ldl -lstdc++ -lm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,$(HDF5)/lib -I $(HDF5)/include
```

And clearly the intended target is `testr`, and the source ought to be a prerequisite:

```
testr: testr.c
    gcc testr.c -L$(HDF5)/lib -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -ldl -lstdc++ -lm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,$(HDF5)/lib -I $(HDF5)/include
```

Add a couple of automatic variables:

```
testr: testr.c
    gcc $< -o $@ -L$(HDF5)/lib -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -ldl -lstdc++ -lm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,$(HDF5)/lib -I $(HDF5)/include
```

That's a pretty good rule. We could go a little further, depending on what other targets you'd like Make to build, but that should be enough for now. **Don't forget to test each step of the above, before you adopt the final version.**

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use [predefined implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) and just define appropriate variables and the target:

```
DIR = /usr/local/hdf/hdf5/
INC = $(DIR)include
LIB = $(DIR)lib
CPPFLAGS = -I$(INC)
LDFLAGS = -L$(LIB) -Wl,-rpath,$(LIB)
LOADLIBES = $(LIB)/libhdf5_hl.a $(LIB)/libhdf5.a
LDLIBS = -ldl -lstdc++ -lm

testr:
```

Note that this way as well as with Beta's solution, the output file is named `testr` instead of `a.out` with your original command.